# Error for variable to be initialized but it already is?

Tags: java, initialization

I'm having trouble with my Java code. It's not finished yet but I have an error telling me that the variable disRate has not been initialized but its has been in the else if statements.

This is an extra credit program for an Intro to Java class; it's an algorithm to calculate the final price for a discounted item based on the user's input of quantity and price.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class DiscountDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // start code here

        //variables
        int quantity;
        double itemPrice, totalCost, disRate, disCost, netAmount;

        Scanner get = new Scanner(System.in);

        //user prompt
        System.out.print("Enter the quantity of an item: --> ");
        quantity = get.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter the price of an item: --> ");
        itemPrice = get.nextInt();

        //decision statements
        if(quantity <= 0 || itemPrice <=0)
        {
            System.out.println("\nInvalid Data!\n");

        }
        else if(quantity <= 9)
        {
            disRate = 0;

        }//if quantity <=9 end
        else if(quantity >= 10 && quantity <= 19)
        {
            disRate = .1;

        }//if quantity >=10 || <= 19 end
        else if(quantity >= 20 && quantity <= 49)
        {
            disRate = .2;

        }//if quantity >=20 || <= 49 end
        else if(quantity >= 50 && quantity <=99)
        {
            disRate = .3;

        }//if quantity >=50 || <= 99 end
        else if(quantity >= 100)
        {
            disRate = .35;

        }//if quantity >=100 end

        //calculation
        totalCost = quantity * itemPrice;
        disCost = totalCost * disRate;
        netAmount = itemPrice - disCost;


    } //main end

} //class end
```

Comment: Check *all* the paths. Unrelated: a lot of those comments are just noise.

Comment: Change `double itemPrice, totalCost, disRate, disCost, netAmount;` to `double itemPrice, totalCost, disRate = 0, disCost, netAmount;` (or figure out which code path leaves `disRate` uninitialized). Why make that last `else if` an `else if` (since it seems it should cover all remaining values, just make it an `else`).

Comment: @ScaryWombat That will not initialize it if it’s the error condition.

Comment: @DaveNewton Yep, you are right (of course)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you initialize `disRate`only within a `IF` statement and if all the boolean condition is false `disRate` will be never initialized and the math on `disCost = totalCost * disRate;` could be not be done.

The IDE detects this situation and asks you to initialize `disRate` with a value.

Just do `double disRate = 0;` at the start of your code or add a `else` statement to initialize `disRate`.

Comment: Thank you! Making the last statement else didn't do much (still added it just in case) but changing the declared variable to disRate = 0 worked!

Answer (score 0):

You just declared it, not initialized. 
You do not have an else, just have if-elseif, of course that when the value is greater or equal to 100 will enter at the last if-else, but the compiler can not be so smarter.

```
    } else if(quantity >= 50 && quantity <=99){
        disRate = .3;

    }else  {
        disRate = .35;
    }
```

Comment: That will not initialize it if it’s the error condition.